# ie8 in winxp - jquery plugin lost in callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

With IE8 under windowsXP, colorbox object is undefined after reload page

On first page load, alert is ok

On click to "click me", alert is ok

On click to "reload", page is reloaded and alert is ok

On click to "click me", alert is undefined!

This happens only in IE8 on second (and next) load.
Maybe it is related to cache, i tried local resources, uncompressed resources, nothing helped

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xuq93/1/show/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/colorbox/1.4.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert($.colorbox);
        $('#text').bind('click', function()
        {
            alert($.colorbox);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<span id="text">click to alert</span>
<a href="?">reload page</a>
```

Comment: you are including another version of jquery somewhere. Not quite sure why you concluded that this had anything to do with your OS or Browser. And, jsfiddle DOES work with IE8, go to the fiddleurl/show

Comment: Test html page i wrote http://webarea.cz/ie8test.html has only one jquery and colorbox version. It works right in all major browsers, except ie8 on windowsXP. Thank you for message about jsfiddle and ie8.

Comment: sorry i can't follow links

Comment: here is jsfiddle version (direct show link, but due to some jsfiddle logic behind, it doesn't work in ie8) http://jsfiddle.net/Xuq93/1/show/
I will try it on more versions of ie8, thank you!